# AJAX call cross domain issue

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to login to my wordpress site using ajax call, which i asked in [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134882/login-to-wordpress-site-from-my-site). It should not respond anything back. But whenever i call this ajax function, Firefox(firebug) is showing 200 OK in red. This must be a cross domain issue. Tried too many things but no luck so far. Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "http://path-to-wordpress/wp-login.php",
         data:myData
         success: function(data){

         },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        }   
});
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: are you trying from two different domains?

Comment: If you want to login to your worldpress which is hosted on another server, I can suggest you another method, not through ajax

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: You JS code is wrong. You can't name a variable as `my-data` and a missing `,` after my-data.

Comment: @Muthu Kumaran both are sub domain to each other like one is like abc.com and other is like dev.abc.com

Comment: Sorry it may be unrelated but sometimes its very efficient for me to Do something like the following, you need to find the wp form action with a full path and form html.
$formHtml = '<html><body>
        <form id="form_name" action="wordpress_action_path" name="interspire_form" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="ss_username" value="'.$membersInfo->username.'">
        <input type="hidden" name="ss_password" value="'.$membersInfo->password.'">       </form>        </body></html>       <script language="javascript"> document.form_name.submit()</script>';
echo $formHtml;exit;

Comment: @TariqAziz: I have already tried this, but it gives the same error too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your JS code is on `abc.com` and your wordpress site is `dev.abc.com`.

To fix cross domain issue, just add the following code to `.htaccess` file to your wordpress site (`dev.abc.com`)

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(abc\.com)$" origin_is=$0 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
```

Just replace `(abc\.com)` with a proper site name. For eg: `(google\.com)` or `(yahoo\.com)`

Comment: Actually the Zend application is on dev.abc.com and wordpress is on abc.com. i know its weird, but the wordpress was built and already installed by another company for this client, and now I have this project.

Comment: can you able to add that piece of code to the wordpress site?

Answer (score 1):

Set the dataType to `JSONP`, in your ajax call and it will work cross-domain

For refrence ot ajax call visit [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I don't expect any response from server.

Answer (score 1):

There is property named crossDomain of $.ajax. Please set it to true.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) in you `wp-login.php` page.

[Here's how to do it](http://enable-cors.org/)

But given the nature of the page, be extra cautious : **don't allow all origins (*) but only your site**. If you allow all, your users could have their login info stolen.